# about order of number

Tags: number-theory

prove that if $n\in N$，（ab，n)=1,$(ord_na,ord_nb)$=1,then
$ord_n(ab)=ord_na\cdot ord_nb$

My attempt suppose $a’=ord_na$,$b’=ord_nb$
then $a^{a’}\equiv 1 \pmod n$. $b^{b’} \equiv 1 \pmod n$
Then I can get $(ab)^{a’b’} \equiv 1\pmod n$
The next I should proof a’b’=$ord_nab$,I think I may use (a’,b’)=1, I think if I proof for any h such that $(ab)^h\equiv 1\pmod n$ we have a’b’|h,then we finish .but I can’t figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** $ $ If $\,(ab)^{\large k}\! = 1\,$ let $\,c = a^{\large k}\! = b^{\large -k}\,$ so $\,c^{\large a'}\!\!=1=c^{\large b'}\!$ $\Rightarrow {\rm ord}\, c = c'\mid a',b'$ *coprimes*, so $c' = 1$ hence $\,c = 1,\,$ therefore $\,a^k = 1 = b^k,\,$ so $\,a',b'\mid k\,$ so their lcm $\,a'b'\mid k$

Comment: Sorry I can’t understand you signal ,can you write more explicit

Comment: @user603994 What part can't you understand?

Comment: $1=c^b’$,and what is mean ord c=c’|a’

Comment: $x = 1 = y\,$ means $\,x=1,\, y= 1\,$  The 2nd means  $c$ has order $c'$ and $c'$ divides $a'$ (because $c^{\large a'}= 1),\,$ and similar for $\,b'\ \ $

Comment: but why $c^b’=1$

Comment: @user603994 $\ c^{\large b'}\!\! = (b^{\large -k})^{\large b'}\!\! = (b^{\large b'})^{\large -k}\! = 1^{\large -k}\! = 1\ \ $

Comment: But Why a’|k,b’|k

Comment: @user603994  $\ a\,$ has order $\,a'$ so $\,a^{\large k}=1\,\Rightarrow\, a'\mid k.\ $ Do you know that property of the order?

Comment: thanks I understand

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

As you have shown $$(ab)^{a’b’}\equiv 1\pmod{n}.$$

Now, suppose the order of $ab$ is $a_1 b_1$, where $a_1$ is a divisor of $a’$ and $b_1$ is a divisor if $b’$. This means there are integers $a_2, b_2$ such that $$a_1 a_2=a’, \quad b_1b_2=b’.$$

Now $$a^{a_1b_1}b^{a_1b_1}\equiv1\pmod{n}.$$ Consider what happens when you raise this congruence to $a_2$ and use the fact that $a’$ and $b’$ are coprime to prove $b_1=b’$. Similarly for $a’$.

**Edit:**

Sorry, there were a few mistakes in my post, which I have cleared up. Since you are still stuck, more explicitly, raising to $a_2$ gives $$b^{a’b_1}\equiv1\pmod{n}$$ and so $b’$ must divide $a’b_1$. Clearly it cannot divide $a’$ and so must divide $b_1$. Since $b_1$ divides $b’$, this means $b_1=b’$. The same argument shows $a’=a_1$.

**Edit 2:**

Here is a proof for the existence of the integers $a_1$ and $b_1$:

First, let  $x$ be any integer coprime to $n$, such that the order of $x$ is $m$. We will show that, if $$x^k\equiv1\pmod{n},$$ for some integer $k$, then $m$ divides $k$.

Assume, for contradiction, $m$ does not divide $k$, then $$k=mq +r,$$ where $1\leq r\lt m$. Thus $$x^k\equiv x^{mq+r}\equiv x^{mq}x^{r}\equiv x^r\equiv1\pmod{n},$$ which is a contradiction, since $m$ is the *smallest* integer power of $x$ congruent to $1$ modulo $n$.

It now follows that, if $m$ is the order of $ab$, then $m$ divides $a’b’$. Assume $m$ only divides $a’$, then $$mk=a’.$$ However,  $$\left(a^mb^m\right)^k\equiv1\pmod{n}\\\implies b^{a’}\equiv1\pmod{n}$$ and the last congruence implies $b’$ divides $a’$, which is a contradiction. Thus, $$m=a_1 b_1$$ where $a_1$ is a factor of $a’$ and $b_1$ is a factor of $b’$.

Comment: But why $a_1$is a divisor of a’

Comment: Sorry I still can’t. Proof $a_1=a$

Comment: @user603994 the order of $ab$ must divide $a’b’$ and since $a’$ and $b’$ are coprime there must exist such integers $a_1, b_1$.

Comment: But if $a’|a_1$,$b’|a_1$also satisfy

Comment: @user603994 I have edited my post, hopefully it makes sense now, sorry I did not mean to write $a_1=a$.

Comment: but why the order of ab can decompose to $a_1,b_1$ which satisfy $a_1|a’,b_1|b’$,why not $a_1|a’,b_1|b’$

Comment: @user603994 I am sorry, I do not quite understand your question: you seem to have written the same thing twice.

Comment: I mean as (a’,b’)=1,then we get $a_1|a’$or $a_1|b’$,so do $b_1$,but why can we suppose $a_1|a’,b_1|b’$

Comment: @user603994 I have updated again, to explicitly prove the existence of $a_1$ and $b_1$.

Comment: Wow thanks you write so clear

Answer (score 0):

First prove (Ia): If $x\in \Bbb Z^+$ and $a^x\equiv 1 \pmod n$ then $a'\,|x.$ Similarly, (Ib): If $y\in \Bbb Z^+$ and $b^y\equiv 1 \pmod n$ then $b'\,|y.$

Let $z=$ord$_n(ab).$

Then  modulo $n$  we have $$1\equiv (ab)^{a'z}\equiv (a^{a'})^z \cdot b^{a'z}\equiv 1^z\cdot b^{a'z}\equiv b^{a'z}.$$ So  $b'\,|a'z$ by (Ib). Now $(a',b')=1,$ so $b'\,|a'z\implies b'|z.$

Similarly, by (Ia) we have  $1\equiv(ab)^{b'z}\equiv a^{b'z}\implies a'\,|b'z\implies a'\,|z.$

Now $a',b'$ are co-prime divisors of $z,$ so $a'b'\,|z.$

Therefore ord$_n(ab)= z\geq a'b'.$

And since $(ab)^{a'b'}\equiv 1$ we also have ord$_n(ab)\leq a'b'.$

Comment: To prove (Ia) : Since $x\geq a'$ by def'n of ord$_n(a),$ there exist non-negative integers $q, r$ with $x=a'q+r$ and $0\leq r<a'.$ Now $1\equiv a^x\equiv (a^{a'})^q\cdot a^r\equiv a^r.$ But $(0\leq r<a'=$ord$_n(a)\land a^r\equiv 1)$ implies $ r=0.$ So $x=qa'+r=qa'.$ So $a'\,|x.$